# Calling another powershell script from first one

Tags: powershell

I am a very newbie to powershell.
I just learnt scripting hello world in power shell.

But, I have a task which i need to complete.

From my hello world powershell (Say 'Script One') , I want to call another powershell (say 'Script Two'), which I am able to do.
But in Script Two, I want to pass different credentials.

So Script One should call Script Two with the credentials I mention.

Can anyone please help me up.

```
Script One (My first script script) :
Write-Host “Hello, World!”
invoke-expression -Command "C:\Scripts\Script Two.ps1"  **[BUT CALL WITH THE CREDENTIALS I WANT]**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your first script :

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("OTHERLOGIN", (ConvertTo-SecureString "OTHERPASSOWRD" -AsPlainText -Force))

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "-File 'C:\Scripts\Script Two.ps1'"
```

But storing credendials in a script is a bad habit, so you could use this instead (will prompt you for login/password for the second script) :

```
$credential = Get-Credential
```